# Why does android:listSelector incorrectly change from Activity to Activity

Tags: android, listview, selector

Steps to reproduce - this happens on Android 4.2.2 - I did not see it happen on Android 4.2.1

1. Answer a few questions, exit app
2. Come back into app
3. select a question set - it's holo_LIGHT_blue
4. goto another Activity (e.g. Info Screen) and come back
5. select a question set - it's holo_DARK_blue
6. NOTE: I am not not modifying android:list_selector, I am using default Android.

Do you think something is being cached by the system?

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/landing_lv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@color/white_alpha"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:animationCache="false"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:padding="0dip" />
```

This is the URL for the app if you want to try it out, but I think the question can be answered without downloading it. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.txt2lrn.www

[image: Before - light blue]
[image: After - dark blue]

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bug with Android because the same odd behavior occurs with Google Currents.
Notice light blue on left, dark blue on right.  Note that this occurs on Android 4.2.x and not on Android 4.3

Filed Android Bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=50196

[image: Before]
[image: After]